# Error number 2202 when creating user group for sql server 2008 using C# VS 2008 in Vista

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to create user group for registered in SQL Server 2008.

This is my code :

```
[DllImport("Netapi32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
internal static extern int NetLocalGroupAdd([In, MarsharAS(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]     string serverName,[In] int level, [In] reg NativeHeaders.LOCALGROUP_INFO_1 info0, out int     paramError);

internal struct LOCALGROUP_INFO_1
{
    public string lgrpi1_name;
    public string lgrpi1_comment;
}  

$ always return error number 2202( User name not valid )
Public void CreateWinAuthGroup ()
{
        var localgroup_info_ = new LOCALGROUP_INFO_1
        {
            lgrpi1_name = "TesUserGroup",
            lgrpi1_comment = "Group for My Application"
        }
         int error = NetLocalGroupAdd(serverName, 0, ref localgroup_info_, out paramerror);

}
```

Has anyone else faced this issue? This source running well on my standalone test application. But always returns error when integrated with main application.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Um, did you miss an end quote after the group name?

Comment: ups...sorry, I will edit my post.

Comment: Is your code running as system, or as a privilaged user?

Comment: I did as administrator for my vista home premium.

Comment: Still Error....anyone can help me resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error.it's because I doing testing using my custom string group user name. so it will be running well. but on real class, error is because username group format not valid. error 2202 is : [error number description for Terminal Server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/186555) . So the problem is closed.